# Use passed data in form angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, mean-stack

I am currently trying to complete my CRUD in an application I am making with the MEAN stack.

But I am having troubles completing the update function.
In my home.ejs, I have a selections of names(patients) and when I choose one of these, their data will show up. Then I have a button, which directs me to Details.ejs, which, based on the passed _id, will show the correct function.
Which is does. However, now I need a form, which will take passed data, and make it updatable.

How might I go about this?

Details.ejs

```
<div>
{{patient.name}}
<form novalidate class="form">
Name: <input type="text" ng-model="title" /><br>
Age: <input type="text" ng-model="age" /><br>
<input type="text" ng-model="id" style="display:none;">
<input type="submit" ng-click="update(patient)" value="Save">
</form>



</div>
```

Detailscontroller:

```
.controller('detailsCtrl', [
        '$scope',
        '$stateParams',
        'patients',
        'patient',
        function($scope, $stateParams, patients, patient){

                console.log(patient.name)
                console.log(patient._id)

                $scope.title = patient.name;
                $scope.age = patient.age;


        $scope.patient = patient
        $scope.update = function(patient){ 

                patients.update({

                        name: $scope.title,
                        age: $scope.age
                })
            };

    }])


;
```

And for good measure, the factory method and the route:

```
 object.update = function(patient) {
    return $http.put('/patients/' + patient._id ).success(function(data) {
            object.patients.push(data)
        });
 };
```

Route:

```
router.put('/patients/:patient', function(req, res, next) {
    req.patient.update(function(err, patient) {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      res.json(patient);
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems like the form is already updateable...?

Comment: Thanks for replying! Unfortunately not, when I look in my console, it says that it can put, because the id is undefined. Which means, I think, it doesn't pass the patient data along the submit button.

PUT http://localhost:3000/patient/undefined

Comment: you aren't passing the id to patients.update.  you are only passing name and age.

Comment: Still no go, I think the form need the complete patient data passed along. Like iterate through the passed data within the form.

Comment: you can't just pass patient to patients.update() ?

Comment: I misunderstood you before I guess. I tried to _id: patient._id, which actually passes the ID. So thanks for that!

However, I get this now:
PUT http://localhost:3000/patients/565dbc3867b950702a63777b 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: This might be a hint, though...

After applying the update to the document {_id: ObjectId('565cadc299dde61413d46daf') , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: ObjectId('565dbc3867b950702a63777b')